# jquery doesn't seem to work for the date picker range?

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net

Using ASP.NET MVC (C#), I have these codes;

form.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="birthday" class="cols-sm-2 control-label text-dark">Birthday</label>
   <div class="cols-sm-10">
       <div class="input-group">
           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Birthday", @type = "date", @id = "datepicker" , @name = "datepicker" } })
       </div>
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

the script, which I put at the bottom-most since it did not also work inside the  tag;

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
    $(function DateRange() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1950:2007"
        });
    });
</script>
```

[the result when code is ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OllgZ.png)

basically it should show that the max date available for choosing is 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `maxDate` option to your `datepicker`. It will look like this:

```
<script>
    $(function DateRange() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1950:2007",
            maxDate: new Date(2007, 11, 31)
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above specification will allow you to select the date till 31st Dec 2007 and it will hide the future dates.